# ASP.NET reuse same style for Gridview and DetailsView globally

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview, styling, detailsview

I am new to ASP.NET

Basically, I have a format style that using for a Gridview (example below).  This is inside the Gridview.  Anytime I create another Gridview in a different page. I would have to copy and paste this style again.  I wonder if there is another way (like CSS class) where I can globally save this code and just Reference it in the Gridview?

```
<AlternatingRowStyle ForeColor="Black"  BackColor="#F7F6F3"  VerticalAlign="top" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#B5DAFF" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="center" />
        <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black"  
        Width="20%" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <CommandRowStyle BackColor="Green" Font-Bold="True" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="Gold" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />    
        <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"  BackColor="Gold" />
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these properties of the GridView: `CssClass`, `PagerStyle-CssClass` and `AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass`. Then you just define the styles globally in your .css file using the classes you just applied to the GridView.

Like this sample:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomres" runat="server"  
    DataSourceID="customresDataSource"   
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
    GridLines="None"  
    AllowPaging="true"  
    CssClass="mGrid"  
    PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"  
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">  
    <Columns>  
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="Company Name" />  
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact Name" />  
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactTitle" HeaderText="Contact Title" />  
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" />  
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />  
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" />  
    </Columns>  
</asp:GridView>
```

**CSS**

```
.mGrid {   
    width: 100%;   
    background-color: #fff;   
    margin: 5px 0 10px 0;   
    border: solid 1px #525252;   
    border-collapse:collapse;   
}  
.mGrid td {   
    padding: 2px;   
    border: solid 1px #c1c1c1;   
    color: #717171;   
}  
.mGrid th {   
    padding: 4px 2px;   
    color: #fff;   
    background: #424242 url(grd_head.png) repeat-x top;   
    border-left: solid 1px #525252;   
    font-size: 0.9em;   
}  
.mGrid .alt { background: #fcfcfc url(grd_alt.png) repeat-x top; }  
.mGrid .pgr { background: #424242 url(grd_pgr.png) repeat-x top; }  
.mGrid .pgr table { margin: 5px 0; }  
.mGrid .pgr td {   
    border-width: 0;   
    padding: 0 6px;   
    border-left: solid 1px #666;   
    font-weight: bold;   
    color: #fff;   
    line-height: 12px;   
 }     
.mGrid .pgr a { color: #666; text-decoration: none; }  
.mGrid .pgr a:hover { color: #000; text-decoration: none; }
```

This link has full details: [ASP.NET GridView makeover using CSS](http://atashbahar.com/post/GridView-makeover-using-CSS.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use a .skin file in themes and add the theme in the web.config.

When you create your gridview in the skin file, do not include the ID, you can assign a skin ID so you can have multiple versions of it, and have gridviews that do not use it

```
 <system.web>
  <pages styleSheetTheme="ThemeName" />
</system.web>
```